# Git command to get SVN style diff; modified file list between revisions

Tags: gitlab, git

I used the command `"git diff --name-only"` and got output like below

```
FilePath/FilePath/FileName.ext
FilePath/FilePath1/FileName1.ext
```

I need SVN style output like

```
M FilePath/FilePath/FileName.ext
A FilePath/FilePath1/FileName1.ext
```

How to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the "--name-status" option instead of "--name-only":

```
git diff --name-status
```

Example output:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD~1 HEAD
M       .gitignore
A       src/File1.java
A       src/File2.java
M       src/File3.java
```